# Cannot call Class with package name in PL file

Tags: eclipse, openedge, progress-4gl

I have create a PL for example : vhpFO1ui.pl with PROLIB syntax and add (arl_listUI.r) into it.
PROPATH in .ini are set to the PL file directory path.

There are 2 cases :

1. a program called arl_listUI.r in PL it returns an error. (source with package name).
   [image]
2. I have tried to remove package name in source file (.cls), compile and add it into PL. When a program called it, it's just crash. No .exe left in task manager either. (without package name).

P.S. : It works well if the programs (.r) are placed in directory (with package name). There are thousands of programs, it would be better if it works with PL (for long-term update on client side).

Any suggestion?

Comment: When you add procedural rcode to a PL you have to make sure the relative paths within the PL are correct. Have you ensured that this is the case with your OO .r? I've never worked with OO in a PL so I don't know if this is the case, but it's worth asking the question.

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify:

> are set to the PL file directory path.

The PL needs to be referenced as a file path in the PROPATH.

Comment: thanks for your clarification Mike, and yes it does referenced as file path in the PROPATH.

Comment: When you do the prostrct list, is the r-code for your class in the vphFO1ui folder?

And a side remark: You should rethink your class naming strategy...

Comment: Yes r-code are in the vhpFO1ui folder. Do you mean prolib <name>.pl -l perhaps? Screenshot link :  https://mega.nz/#!q5YHSI6T!EknsY20C3Vo0HhmKk8Nkmt14jXwOjMzYSV4smN0AQ8o

Comment: You .pl contians absolute file names (starting with c:\e1-vhp\vhplib). But the files should be added with a relative path name.